# python code to select all probability

Tags: python

Python code to select all probability in (TEST)

I use code like this code:

```
TEST = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]

DX = random.choice(TEST)

for x in range(0, 5):
    print(DX)
```

it's print to me like this: test1(5 times) or test2(5 times) and soo on .....

and this code :

```
TEST = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]

for x in TEST:
    print(x)
```

didn't work.

are there any code to choice some thing like this (test1, then test2, then test3, then test4, then test5)

thanks ....

Comment: put `random.choice(TEST)` in your loop

Comment: By select all probability, do you mean seed the pseudo random number generator?

Comment: I need some code to choice number from 1 to 100

first choice 1
second choice 2

and soo on

Answer (score 2):

```
test = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]

# Selects a random value and stores in dx.
dx = random.choice(test)

for x in range(0, 5):
    # Prints the value stored in dx.
    print(dx)
```

Do you see the problem? The code selected a random value only once, so it prints the same value five times. To fix it, you need to select a new value each loop:

```
test = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]

for x in range(0, 5):
    # Selects a random value and stores in dx.
    dx = random.choice(test)
    # Prints the value stored in dx.
    print(dx)
```

Or more simply:

```
test = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]

for x in range(5):
    print(random.choice(test))
```

Also take care of your variables names. It's recommended to use lower case, with underscores when you need spaces, and name them based on what they should contain. "Test" is not very descriptive and may give people a hard time to understand the code when it's used.

Comment: can I use code to gives figures for consecutive

I use this : str(random.randrange(1, 100))

but it isn't start from number(1)

Comment: You mean a list of numbers from 1 to 100? `random`, as the name implies, chooses a number randomly in the interval. Try `range(1, 100)` for a list of all numbers, in order, between 1 and 99. And if this solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: thanks. but I need it to choice first "1" then "2" then "3" and and and even "100"

can I do it ?

thanks u.

Comment: # coding: utf-8

import random

for x in range(100):
 print("Hello ! "+ range(1))
 

I need it to print first time : "Hello ! 1" then "Hello ! 2"

Comment: Like this? `for i in range(1, 101): print("Hello", i)`